# Correct way to use ninject within an webapi actionfilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, ninject

I have been given a webapi2 application to manage and I've started to write some unit tests for it as it didn't have any.

Testing controllers and services are both pretty easy to do as they are injecting their dependencies via constructor injection.

For the actionfilters I see things are done differently as its not possible to use constructor injection.

Now I haven't really used ninject much before but this an example of how the filters have been setup.

```
public class CustomFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public ILog Log { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var id = int.Parse(actionContext.ActionArguments["id"].ToString());
        Log = actionContext.Request
            .GetDependencyScope()
            .GetService(typeof(ILog))
            as ILog;


     Log.WriteMessage(string.Format("Got id:{0}",id));

   }
}
```

My registration looks like

```
kernel.Bind<ILog>().ToConstant(new Log());
```

Does this look ok? I am not sure how to write a test for the filter, do I somehow need to mock the `.GetDependencyScope` to include my required `ILog`?

The way Log is getting wired up within the filter is this right?

Comment: See [Passive Attributes](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/). I realize Ninject has "solved" this issue in a completely different way, but it is always better to make an application that works with or without a specific DI container so you can swap it at any time, or even use [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/).

Answer (score 1):

In order to access it via the `DependencyResolver` you need to register it with the http configuration.

```
public class NinjectDependencyResolver : NinjectDependencyScope, IDependencyResolver, System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver {
   private readonly IKernel kernel;

   public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel)
       : base(kernel) {
       this.kernel = kernel;
   }

   public IDependencyScope BeginScope() {
       return new NinjectDependencyScope(this.kernel.BeginBlock());
   }
}
```

And then register it during startup...

```
// Use the kernal and the NinjectDependencyResolver as
// application's resolver
var resolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernal);

//Register Resolver for Web Api
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
```

You can access the resolver via the ActionContext

```
public class CustomFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public ILog Log { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
        var id = int.Parse(actionContext.ActionArguments["id"].ToString());
        Log = actionContext
            .RequestContext
            .Configuration
            .DependencyResolver
            .GetService(typeof(ILog))
            as ILog;


       Log.WriteMessage(string.Format("Got id:{0}",id));
   }
}
```